# I need to use an SSL certificate for Linux and Windows. Will my Linux certificates stop working if I re-issue a certificate for my Windows Server?

Tags: openssl

I am new to this whole SSL thing. I need to use the wildcard certificate I bought on multiple Linux servers and a Windows server. I already installed (?) them on the Linux servers, but I'm having problems installing them on Windows (following this: https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/microsoft-iis-8-ssl-installation/). I am assuming that I need to re-issue a new certificate for the Windows server since it is using IIS 7. My question is, if I reissue the certificate with a new public key, will the already installed certificated stop working? Apologies for the beginner question, I just want to make sure I'm doing things right.

Comment: If other certificate is needed, you ca reissue it for *the same* primary key. But first explain what problems exactly you have.

Comment: The link you give is for the case where the CSR and privatekey were generated _in IIS_, which is not your case, so they don't apply and don't work. Instead _create_ a PFX/PKCS12 as answered by Mikael H, then see the second half (import) of https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-export/export-ssl-from-microsoft-iis-8/ .

Answer (score 1):

No need to regenerate anything: Windows simply uses a different format for storing certificates (often suffixed pfx or p12) than what many Linux services do (usually suffixed pem or crt).

It's relatively straightforward to convert between such file or container formats using openssl which comes preinstalled on many Linux distributions. Do a web search for `openssl convert pem pfx`, for example. You will need your wildcard certificate and a CA intermediary certificate, both of which you would have received from your CA when ordering the certificate, along with its private key, which you generated with the original certificate request.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a wildcard certificate, it is by design to be used on multiple servers.
Just make sure the common name and alternative subject matches the hostname/dns name of the server.
I second Mikael's proposition, to generate a request from the windows server (be sure to fill the SAN field to avoid warnings on CHrome), generate a pfx with it on your Cert Authority and then upload it as per your link